# How to use exports default with a basic function for testing

Tags: javascript

I've been altering this code for hours and I think it's finally time to ask for help. It's pretty simple, but it doesn't work. I get Customers === undefined

```
// customers.test.js

import { expect } from 'chai';
import { Customers } from './customers.server.js';

/* eslint-env mocha */

describe('Customers', () => {
  it('customers returns 1', () => {
    expect(Customers).to.eq(1);
  });
});
```

The above code is working properly, except Customers is undefined. Here's the server controller I'm testing.

```
 // customers.server.js

 function test1() {
   return 1;
 }

 export default test1();
```

Comment: Well you aren't exporting a `Customers` class or function. Did you mean to do `import {test1 as Customers} from './customers.server.js';`?

Comment: Or rather I guess you meant to write `import Customers from './customers.server.js';` (note that I removed the braces) - See the [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Importing_defaults) for more details

Comment: The MDN documentation (linked in the above comment) contains everything you need to know.

Comment: Btw, having the function is useless, you could just do `export default 1;`.